# AsyncTask doInBackground will not finish/hangs

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've got a AsyncTask that will not finish when I have my `lib.roomAvailable()` call in the doInBackground method. When QueueTask is called a progressDialog will show and
it sticks. It should go away after 5 seconds.

If I remove `lib.roomAvailable()` from the doInBackground method everything work as expected. Why do I get this strange behaviour when I call `lib.roomAvailable()`?

`roomAvailable()` calls another AsyncTask can this be an issue?

```
    public class QueueTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Library lib;
    private String date;
    private int room;
    private int time;
    private String user;
    private String id;

    public QueueTask(String date, int room, int time, String user, String id) {
        this.date = date;
        this.room = room;
        this.time = time;
        this.user = user;
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        lib = new Library();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ManageRoomActivity.this, "Queuing", "Queuing process", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int timer = 5;
            while(timer > 0) {
                if(lib.roomAvailable(date, room, time)) {
                                Log.w("RoomAvailable", "Room Available");
                            }
                android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                timer --;
                Log.w("TIMER", "" + timer);
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
                return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ManageRoomActivity.this, DatePickerActivity.class);
        ManageRoomActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
public boolean roomAvailable(String date, int room, int time) {
          boolean available = false;

          String timeString = "";
          if(time < 10)
              timeString = "0";
          timeString = timeString + time;

          String roomNum = "";
          if(room < 10) 
              roomNum = "0";  

          roomNum = roomNum + room;
          AsyncTask<String, Void, String> readSource = new URL_Source();
          String source = "";
        try {
            String uri = getURI(date);
            source = readSource.execute(getURI(date)).get();
            String[] chunks =  source.split("<td");
              for(String chunk:chunks) {
                  if(chunk.contains(date) & chunk.contains("=Grp" + roomNum) & chunk.contains("stid=" + timeString))
                      available = true;
              }
              return available;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return available;
      }
```

The other AsyncTask:

```
public final class URL_Source extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

public URL_Source() {

}

protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri[0]);
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            source.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        return source.toString();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "ERROR";
}
```

}

Solution:

I didn't have a clue how AsyncTask worked. You cannot call a AsynchTask within a AsyncTask!

Comment: you have try after removing or commenting `android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);` ?

Comment: Can you show lib.roomAvailable(date, room, time)?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя That don't do any difference I'm afraid
@ Araw see Edit 1 please.
@ Neurenor, I'm not sure what kind of stack trace you want. Of current thread?

Comment: Have you checked that your application does not hang in the other Async task here:         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            source.append(line);
        }
?

Comment: If I do a Log.w("TEST", "" + lib.roomAvailable(date, room, time)) in the onPreExecute() it will log and show correct. The log message will not show if it's in the doInBackground() method. @ Araw It seems stop working before that.

Comment: URL_Source doInBackground will not execute it seems. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to create and start an AsyncTask from a thread other than the UI thread.  That is not supported:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

See the section entitled "Threading Rules"